# Taking data from a UserForm in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm busy working on putting together a training logger for staff training using a sidebar in Google Sheets, but I'm coming across a stumbling block when data is being entered from the form in the sidebar to the attached sheet.

When the add button is clicked, it attempts to run the 'addNewRow' function but comes across an error of 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dateUndertaken').  This error continues when I remove the dateUndertaken variable, the error just moves on to the next variable in the list.

Here's my front end code as it currently stands:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="dateUndertaken" class="form-label"><strong>Date Undertaken</strong></label>
          <input type="date" class="form-control" id="dateUndertaken">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="trainingType" class="form-label"><strong>Training Type</strong></label>
          <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
            <option selected></option>
            <option value="Product representative">Product representative</option>
            <option value="Informal staff discussions/training">Informal staff discussions/training</option>
            <option value="Seminar/Webinar">Seminar/Webinar</option>
            <option value="Formal training cource">Formal training cource</option>
            <option value="Technical reading">Technical reading</option>
            <option value="ComplyNZ technical meeting">ComplyNZ technical meeting</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="jobNumber" class="form-label"><strong>CNZ Job Number</strong></label>
          <div id="jobNumberHelp" class="form-text mb-3">Was the training related to assessing a specific job or jobs?  If so, record the job number(s).  If not, enter N/A.</div>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="trainingType">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="trainingTopic" class="form-label"><strong>Topic</strong></label>
          <div id="jobNumberHelp" class="form-text mb-3">This is just a headline, not a full description of the training.</div>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="trainingTopic">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="trainingPurpose" class="form-label"><strong>Purpose</strong></label>
          <div id="jobNumberHelp" class="form-text mb-3">Outline what the purpose of the training was.</div>
          <textarea class="form-control" id="trainingPurpose" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="trainingOutcome" class="form-label"><strong>Outcome</strong></label>
          <div id="trainingOutcomeHelp" class="form-text mb-3">In your own words, describe the outcome of the training, and how you will put it into effect.</div>
          <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="trainingOutcome"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="addButton">Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0pUGZvbkm6XF6gxjEnlmuGrJXVbNuzT9qBBavbLwCsOGabYfZo0T0to5eqruptLy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
      function afterButtonClicked() {
        var dateUndertaken = document.getElementById("dateUndertaken");
        var trainingType = document.getElementById("trainingType");
        var jobNumber = document.getElementById("jobNumber");
        var trainingTopic = document.getElementById("trainingTopic");
        var trainingPurpose = document.getElementById("trainingPurpose");
        var trainingOutcome = document.getElementById("trainingOutcome");
        var rowData = {dateUndertaken:dateUndertaken.value,trainingType:trainingType.value,jobNumber:jobNumber.value,trainingTopic:trainingTopic.value,trainingPurpose:trainingPurpose.value,trainingOutcome:trainingOutcome.value};
        google.script.run.addNewRow(dateUndertaken,trainingType,jobNumber,trainingTopic,trainingPurpose,trainingOutcome);
      }
      document.getElementById("addButton").addEventListened("click",afterButtonClicked);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the back end code/function that appears to be giving me the problems is as follows:

```
function addNewRow(rowData) {
  const dateEntered = new Date();
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  ws.appendRow([rowData.dateUndertaken,rowData.trainingType,rowData.jobNumber,rowData.trainingTopic,rowData.trainingPurpose,rowData.trainingOutcome,dateEntered]);
}
```

If anyone's got some insight as to what's going on it would be much appreciated.  Here's a link to the spreadsheet if anyone wants to take a look over it as well.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/151itI3cX61ilS6k0pkM6rj_G9iw11kXQyXr4_PMHy4E/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- There is no `addEventListened`. It's `addEventListener`. I think that due to this issue, when the HTML is loaded, an error occurs.
- I think that there is no `var jobNumber = document.getElementById("jobNumber")`. `trainingType` might be a dropdown list? And `CNZ Job Number` is `jobNumber`?
- In your Javascript, multiple arguments are used to `addNewRow`. But, in your Google Apps Script, only one argument is used. `rowData` is required to be used in your Google Apps Script.

When these points are reflected in your showing script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this case, please modify your HTML as follows. The Google Apps Script is not modified.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="dateUndertaken" class="form-label"><strong>Date Undertaken</strong></label>
          <input type="date" class="form-control" id="dateUndertaken">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="trainingType" class="form-label"><strong>Training Type</strong></label>
          <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" id="trainingType">
            <option selected></option>
            <option value="Product representative">Product representative</option>
            <option value="Informal staff discussions/training">Informal staff discussions/training</option>
            <option value="Seminar/Webinar">Seminar/Webinar</option>
            <option value="Formal training cource">Formal training cource</option>
            <option value="Technical reading">Technical reading</option>
            <option value="ComplyNZ technical meeting">ComplyNZ technical meeting</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="jobNumber" class="form-label"><strong>CNZ Job Number</strong></label>
          <div id="jobNumberHelp" class="form-text mb-3">Was the training related to assessing a specific job or jobs?  If so, record the job number(s).  If not, enter N/A.</div>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="jobNumber">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="trainingTopic" class="form-label"><strong>Topic</strong></label>
          <div id="jobNumberHelp" class="form-text mb-3">This is just a headline, not a full description of the training.</div>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="trainingTopic">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="trainingPurpose" class="form-label"><strong>Purpose</strong></label>
          <div id="jobNumberHelp" class="form-text mb-3">Outline what the purpose of the training was.</div>
          <textarea class="form-control" id="trainingPurpose" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="trainingOutcome" class="form-label"><strong>Outcome</strong></label>
          <div id="trainingOutcomeHelp" class="form-text mb-3">In your own words, describe the outcome of the training, and how you will put it into effect.</div>
          <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="trainingOutcome"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="addButton">Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      function afterButtonClicked() {
        var dateUndertaken = document.getElementById("dateUndertaken");
        var trainingType = document.getElementById("trainingType");
        var jobNumber = document.getElementById("jobNumber");
        var trainingTopic = document.getElementById("trainingTopic");
        var trainingPurpose = document.getElementById("trainingPurpose");
        var trainingOutcome = document.getElementById("trainingOutcome");
        var rowData = {dateUndertaken:dateUndertaken.value,trainingType:trainingType.value,jobNumber:jobNumber.value,trainingTopic:trainingTopic.value,trainingPurpose:trainingPurpose.value,trainingOutcome:trainingOutcome.value};
        google.script.run.addNewRow(rowData);
      }
      document.getElementById("addButton").addEventListener("click",afterButtonClicked);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### Note:

- When I tested this modified HTML using your Google Apps Script, no error occurred. But, if your actual script is different from the showing scripts, the modified HTML might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.